# WSO2 ESB property incorrect scope

Tags: properties, wso2, esb, mediator

I have next sequence:

```
<payloadFactory>
    <format>
        <cb:accounts/>
    </format>
    <args/>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="accounts" type="OM" expression="//cb:accounts" />
...
<iterate id="accountIterator" continueParent="true" sequential="true" expression="//cb:accounts/cb:accountId">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            ...
            <property name="accounts" type="OM" expression="//*" />
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate> 
<aggregate id="accountIterator">
    <onComplete expression="$body/child::*[fn:position()=1]">
        <log level="custom" />
    </onComplete>
</aggregate>
<enrich>
    <source type="custom" xpath="get-property('accounts')"/>
    <target type="body" />
</enrich>
```

Why property named "accounts" which was set inside "iterate" mediator has null value outside "iterate" mediator ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The flow inside the iterator runs on a separate thread and it is not visible out side. Therefore you can't access a property which is set inside the iterator mediator, outside but vice versa is possible.

Comment: So, there no way to return value from iterate mediator? I need accumulate callout responses inside loop and after this insert this set of responses as child element into body message, how I can do this?

Comment: For this you don't need to access a property defined inside an iterator mediator outside. Inside iterator mediator original message is broken into multiple messages depending on the xpath defined. So inside iterator mediator context there will be multiple messages.

Comment: For your scenario, use call mediator and use aggregator mediator to combine the results. Using call mediator will be more quicker than callout mediator.

Comment: Yes, but I need to use iterate mediator in any case, because I don't know how many child elements I have. At first step I recive XML with list of elements ids and I need make several calls according to elements count. And second step I need unite responses. And finally third step, I need to insert set of united responses into XML with ids.

Comment: In the first step you can use iterator mediator. Inside that you can use send mediator with a receiving sequence defined. So every response will hit that sequence and inside that sequence enrich the id and atlast insert loopback mediator. Then the responses will be forwarded to outSequence and inside outSequence have aggregator mediator. Once aggregated you can use xslt mediator to convert to your format.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling each iteration cycle message context will be cloned and it will only be available in the context inside iterator target. Hence, by default can not get the things doing in synapse/default scope outside the iterator. If you want to store something global, use property with [operation scope](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Property+Mediator).

- Before iterator assign your property to operation scope
- Inside iterator - do modifications
- Outside the iterator - assign your property to default scope (if you want to take it back to default scope)

use below structure for example:

```
    <!--assign your property to operation scope-->
    <property name="ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD"
               expression="get-property('DATA_PAYLOAD')"
               scope="operation"
               type="OM"/>

<iterate xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
              continueParent="true"
              expression="//bookstore/book"
              sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
          <!--if you want to assign the property-->
              <property name="DATA_PAYLOAD"
                        expression="get-property('operation','ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD')"
                        type="OM"/>
         </sequence>
        </target>
</iterate>
     <!--Outside the iterator-->
     <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
               name="NEW_DATA_PAYLOAD"
               expression="get-property('operation','ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD')"
               type="OM"/>
```